# What is the intuitive explanation of the expectation of a mean and variance value in Bishop's PRML book?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, mean

In Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book, there are two equations stated as follows.

Equation 1.57:

$\mathbf{E}[\mu_{ML}] = \mu $

and

Equation 1.58:

$\mathbf{E}[\sigma^2_{ML}] = (\frac{N-1}{N})\sigma^2$

where $\mu_{ML}$ and $\sigma^2_{ML}$ is the maximum likelihood solution for the mean, and variance.

My question is that since $\mu_{ML}$ and $\sigma^2_{ML}$ are already functions of the $N$ dataset, what does it mean when we take the expectation of $\mu_{ML}$ and $\sigma^2_{ML}$ with respect to the dataset again as in the equations 1.57 and 1.58 above? I understand how to prove the equations, but I don't understand what do they mean?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means, if you take several datasets of size $N$, calculate mean and variance estimates for each of them and then take the average, you'd obtain $\mu$ and $\frac{N-1}{N}\sigma^2$